# Default MIME types for REST resource methods

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I am trying to understand the MIME types in RESTful services.If there is a resource method (sayHello) as in below

```
@Path("/customers")
public class CustomerResource {
    @GET
    public String sayHello(){
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

I didn't put any `@Produces` or `@Consumes` annotation on the above method. I have below questions.

1. Is there any default MIME type above method uses to send the response ?
2. Or Does it produce response content type based on "accept-type" from  incoming request ?
3. Can it happen that request does not specify what content type does it accept ? If that is the case, what response content type does above resource method will produce  ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often it will default to `application/octet-stream`, *unless* the client set the `Accept` header, in which case, that's the type that will be used.

One thing you need to be careful about is that there is a not a `MessageBodyWriter` to handle `application/octet-stream` and most types. For instance say you have

```
@GET
public SomeModel get() {}
```

If the client doesn't set a `Accept: application/json` header, then the runtime will look for a `MessageBodyWriter` to that can serialize `SomeModel` to `application/octet-stream`, and it will fail and you will get an exception saying something like "No MessageBodyWriter found for mediatype application/octet-stream and type SomeModel".

So it is always a good idea to put the `@Produces`. Another benefit is that *you* determine what types the endpoint *can* produce. For instance if you have `@Produces("application/json")`, and the client set the `Accept: application/xml` header, then they will get a 406 Not Acceptable error code, which is what *should* happen.

Notice the first paragraph, I used the word *Often*. It is not always the case. For some instances, the the runtime will make assumptions based on the return type. For instance if you return a `String` it is likely the runtime will choose `text/plain`.

But like I said, it's *always* better to have the `@Produces` and `@Consumes` annotations. These are hints not just for the developer but for the runtime to make decisions.